# Stuck at react useEffect for a chain of changes

Tags: reactjs

I'm creating a form builder in react. On a simple text field, I need to:

1. Change `currentValue`
2. When `currentValue` is changed, validate it
3. When validation is done, emit an event (either valid or invalid)

Here's my code:

```
const TextInput = ({ props }) => {

    const [currentValue, setCurrentValue] = useState(props.initialValue);
    const [validationState, setValidationState] = useState(false);
    
    const validate = () => {
        if (!currentValue) {
             setValidationState(false);
        }
        else {
             setValidationState(true);
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        validate();
    }, [currentValue]);

    useEffect(() => {
        emitter.emit('textInputChange', { currentValue, validationState});
    }, [validationState]);
}
```

However, I have this problem now that if I only depend upon `validationState` to emit changes, as soon as `TextInput` becomes valid, emit stops. I need to emit on each change.

But if I depend on `currentValue` too, then since the `validationState` is not sync, I can get invalid state. In other words, the `currentValue` might be valid, but I emit `invalid` from the previously non-updated `validationState`.

How should I solve this?

Comment: If you need to run the `emitter` line for every change, bind it to an `onchange` handler, and don't put it in `useEffect`

Comment: But I need to validate current state before emitting. This is a simplified version. I need to emit onlyl after validation is done.

Comment: So only emit `if (validationState)` ?

Comment: Think about how you would write this without React and useEffect. You're way overthinking this.

Comment: @Evert, without react I have done it a couple of times. With Angular, with jQuery and with AngularJS. And it's not overthinking. It's just that react's setState is not synchronous. That's the entire problem. React in spite of being the number one framework, is not that classy and well-thought. I would rather get a promise from `setState`.

Comment: Ok, try to share your non-react solution. Just call 1 function at a time in an onclick handler.

Comment: "I don't get it, so React must be wrong" is not going to help you get to an answer quicker.

Comment: Let's say Angular. In it state is updated immediately and the next line of code is sure that it deals with committed state. However, I can't just call the one after the other. The overall state is used both in UI of the current field, and in the consumer of the emitted event.

Comment: @Evert, I did not say that of course. I'm spending months on learning and making.

Comment: Did you read my other comments. You may not need `state`. Don't use `useEffect` as an event handler. This is something that sounds like could just be solved with if statements.

Comment: Actually `Viet`s answer seems to be exactly that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you don't need state `validationState`, just update like this with one `useEffect`:

```
const validate = (value) => {
  if (!value) {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
};

useEffect(() => {
  const isValid = validate(currentValue);
  emitter.emit("textInputChange", { currentValue, validationState: isValid });
  
}, [currentValue]);
```

Comment: As I said, I need to emit for both states, either valid or invalid. I can duplicate my validation logic. But that's not a good options.

Comment: @HosseinFallah the updated answer here runs for both cases.